# Validation of a Success or Error Message in Python, using Selenium

Tags: selenium, python

Hi I have created a script to validate for the success or error message after filling the form, but it is throwing an assertion error for everything. Please help me out in fixing this error, Here is my script

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

class demo(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

        cls.driver.get("http://demoqa.com/")


    def test_Click(self):
        self.signup = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Registration').click()

    def test_Form(self):
        self.First_name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='name_3_firstname']").send_keys("Santosh")
        self.Last_name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='name_3_lastname']").send_keys("Kumar")
        self.Status = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pie_register']/li[2]/div/div/input[1]").click()
        self.Hobby = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pie_register']/li[3]/div/div[1]/input[2]").click()
        """self.Country = self.driver.find_element_by_id("dropdown_7")
        for option in self.Country.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
            if option.text == 'India':
                option.click()
                break"""
        self.Country = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("dropdown_7"))
        self.Country.select_by_value('India')
        self.month = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mm_date_8']"))
        self.month.select_by_index(4)
        self.day = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dd_date_8']"))
        self.day.select_by_index(11)
        self.year = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='yy_date_8']"))
        self.year.select_by_value('2014')
        self.phone = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='phone_9']").send_keys("9738993098")
        self.username = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username']").send_keys("santu_tz6")
        self.email = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='email_1']").send_keys("santu6@gmail.com")
        self.about = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='description']").send_keys("Very much interested in Testing")
        self.password = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password_2']").send_keys("Secret97@1")
        self.confirm = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='confirm_password_password_2']").send_keys("Secret97@1")
        self.submit = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pie_register']/li[14]/div/input").click()
        self.success = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='post-49']/div/p").get_attribute('text')
        time.sleep(3)
        self.expected_text = "Error: Username already exists"
        self.assertEquals(self.success,self.expected_text)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
    # close the browser window
        cls.driver.quit()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
         unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch the success or failure message need to replace `get_attribute('text')` to `get_attribute('textContent')`. Simple, but effective.

Comment: Santosh, even though it's your own answer, you should accept it if that is what indeed solved your problem.

Comment: @BharatMane But he found the problem and posted his solution. This *IS* the answer. He was just being polite which is [bad on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) in a weird but reasonable way.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value in the `self.succcess`?

If this is `NULL` or `""`, either your locator is wrong or the error is not displayed at the time of `findElement`. In the second case, you probably need to [wait for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/selenium-python-how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded) is visible before querying its text.

Comment: Hi Joa, I have pasted my complete code, can you please help me in fixing this error..